# Silverlight (3.0) - Data-grid - User adding data via data-grid

Tags: silverlight-3.0, datagrid

I've only been using Silverlight for a little over 24 hours. So I am still finding me feet.

I'm Currently using Silverlight 3 (Beta) (I require its great offline mode feature)

When using the data grid that is bound to a data source, is it possible for users to add data via the grid? Or is the data grid just limited to displaying & editing data from the bound data-source?

Many Thanks
Luke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless something has changed recently, you'll need to add the new row to the data source yourself.  Take a look at this post describing the process:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manishdalal/archive/2008/08/25/silverlight-business-application-part-1-add-new-item.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, it confirmed one of my ideas to add a blank row to the source data to allow the users to add a new item. 

However i will need to look into what happens when users sort the grids.

Comment: Sorting is controlled by instances of the ICollectionView interface.  When you bind an ObservableCollection to a Grid, the Grid creates an instance of this interface (the concrete class is internal - you don't have access to it) behind the scenes.  Then, when you add new items to the underlying data source they should be automatically filtered by the ICollectionView.  hth.