# Possible to insert a new row in a silverlight datagrid from the UI? or only by modifying the datasource?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, silverlight

In WinForms it was possible to add a new row to the grid by using the last row in the grid, some grid controls provide such functionality through the Insert button.

Is this possible with the datagrid included with silverlight?

My only available option is providing input controls to the user with a insert button and manually adding a new row to the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a dupe of this question:

[Silverlight (3.0) - Data-grid - User adding data via data-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840068/silverlight-3-0-data-grid-user-adding-data-via-data-grid/840926#840926)

In short though, the answer is no with the included DataGrid.  You might be able to find a 3rd party component that meets your needs though.